# Does the SYN bit remains 1 in TCP header segment after a successful 3 way hand shake connection between two hosts?

Tags: tcp

Or does it flip back to zero, i know that SYN bit is set to one during the connection formation but what happens to it after that ?

Comment: 1. Off-topic here, maybe on-topic on [networkengineering.se]. 2. SYN is not even set during the whole 3-way handshake as you claim but only in the first message from client to server and the response from the server but not in the final ACK from the client to the server. See [wikipedia:tcp  - connection establishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Connection_establishment)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SYN bit indicates that you wish to synchronize sequence numbers.  Since this is only done one time by each side in the conversation, the bit is reset to zero after the first two packets in the three-way handshake